# Upload an iOS app in AppStore, compatible for a particular iOS version or for a particular device alone

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Since iOS 7 had been released a few months ago, lets say I haven't made any changes to make my app compatible for iOS 7. So, now(Jan 2014) can I upload my app in the Appstore and make it compatible for iOS 6 alone?

Also, can I make my app compatible for a particular iPhone Device alone(say, iPhone 4)?
If I do so, will Apple approve my app?

Comment: Why -1? Isn't this a valuable question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st "Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and **must be optimized for iOS 7**" - Appel Doc.

2nd: You can not make  app compatible for a particular **iPhone Device alone** (say, iPhone 4),
but you can make app only for iPad.

Comment: Ok...but now if i upload my app, it would be compatible only for iPhone 4 with iOS 6. So, will apple will reject my app since, the resolution doesn't support iPhone 5?

Comment: february 1 2014 or 2013?

Comment: It says from Feb 1 2014. So if i upload it now, will they approve my app?

Comment: I'm not 100 % Sure about that.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you cant upload app for iOS6 only and not for iOS7.
And Second you cant add app for device specific.
You can either add it for the `iPhone` or `iPad` or `Universal` (Both).

And you dont want to exclude the iOS7 from your new update bcoz of apple's new [statement](http://www.macrumors.com/2013/12/17/apple-to-require-new-app-store-submissions-to-be-optimized-for-ios-7-on-february-1/).

> Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7.

Comment: It says from Feb 1 2014. So if i upload it now, will they approve my app?

Comment: Yes Definitely it will. But i don't recommend that. I have updated my app today and its on the iTuneStore. And i dont have done anything new for iOS7